# Problem installing socket.io on Fedora Core

Tags: node.js, fedora, socket.io, npm

I'm trying to install `socket.io` on my machine, but I keep encountering errors when I run `npm install socket.io` as directed on their website.  I'm not sure if I have version incompatibilities for npm or node.js or if I'm simply missing something obvious.  As far as I can tell, I have the most recent stable version of both of them.

When I run the install command, the console outputs 40+ errors, and at the end I am given the line `npm not ok`.  Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the error?

Are you installing `npm` using code from `git`? I can only guess that you are not using a stable code, because the master branch from git is often unstable.

If that is the case, what you can do is to get the latest code from the git repository and install it again.

```
$ cd npm
$ git pull
$ make install
```

Hope it will solved your problem.

Comment: `ERR! tar "-mvxpf" "-" "-o" "-C" "/tmp/npm-1315579451606/1315579451606-0.9215416379738599/contents/___package.npm" tar: Ignoring unknown extended header
keyword LIBARC$` This repeats some 40+ times in the error log.  It seems the root of the issue is in unpacking the .tar?  This 'keyword' is not always LIBARC either.. most times it is SCHILY

Comment: The error actually turned out to be an outdated version of tar on my machine, which was unable to read certain header keywords.  Once it was updated, the package was unpacked without error using the method you gave.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an error log if you want anyone to try and troubleshoot your problem. It would also be helpful to know whether you installed Node and NPM from source or RPM. Furthermore, if you installed from source, did you do a standard install or did you make customisations?

If you are able to start from scratch, I suggest following the steps below and seeing how you go. Installing into your home directory won't require root and it makes it easier to clear everything out if you need to start again.

1. Install the stable release of Node in your home directory (use `./configure --prefix=~/Node/`)
2. Set your path as appropriate (ie. `PATH=/home/user/Node/bin:$PATH`)
3. Run the standard NPM installer (`curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`)

Comment: See the comment added on Kelvin's answer for details from the error log.  Thanks for your help, I hope to resolve this soon.